# Custom .tpl.php file cannot be found in Templates folder

Tags: 7, theming

I've created my own theme with a child theme and a custom template file so in the parent's `template.php` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  global $theme; //need this to set $theme as the child theme

  $path = is_file( getcwd() .'/'. drupal_get_path('theme', $theme) . '/mytemplate.tpl.php' ) ? $path_to_child : $path;

  return array(
    'my_template' => array(
     'template' => 'mytemplate',
     'render element' => 'my_template',
     'path' => $path,
    ),
  );
}
```

It works but I feel this is clumsy. Also it doesn't find the new template if I put it in the templates folder. You can see that I've had to do an `is_file()` to look for the `mytemplate.tpl.php` file in the child theme.

I want my search order to be as follows:

- themes/child_theme/templates/mytemplate.tpl.php
- themes/child_theme/mytemplate.tpl.php
- themes/parent_theme/templates/mytemplate.tpl.php
- themes/parent_theme/mytemplate.tpl.php

This already works with `page.tpl.php` so clearly I'm missing something. Drupal can find `page.tpl.php` pretty much anywhere I put it. How do I make this work with my own custom template?